# How to evaluate refinement of a function when calling this function in Red/Rebol

Tags: rebol, red, rebol3, rebol2

```
>> f: func [x /a][either a [x + 2] [x + 1]]
== func [x /a][either a [x + 2] [x + 1]]

>> b: /a
== /a

>> f/b 1
*** Script Error: f has no refinement called b
*** Where: f
*** Stack: f  

>> f/:b 1
*** Script Error: f has no refinement called :b
*** Where: f
*** Stack: f
```

You can see that the function `f` has a `refinement a`, and I bind `/a` to `b`. When calling `f` with its refinement `/a` by `b`, it fails.

What is the correct way to pass a refinement which needs to be evaluated before to its function? Or, is there a way to convert a `path!` to `function!`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refinements are limited, in a way that they can be passed only by being listed literally in a function call. On the other hand, you can construct such function call (a `path!` value followed by all the arguments) whichever way you want:

```
>> b: 'a
== a
>> do probe reduce [to path! reduce ['f b] 1]
[f/a 1]
== 3
```

Note that elements of the path in this case are `word!`s, not `refinement!`s. In general, such use-case is covered by `apply`. However, only Rebol has it natively, and with an awkward calling convention:

```
>> f: func [x /a][either a [x + 2] [x + 1]]
>> b: yes
== true
>> apply :f [1 b]
== 3
>> apply :f [1 no]
== 2
```

You can easily write your own high-level version of it if that's what you need.

Comment: Perfect solution! And another method under your point: `b: "/a" do rejoin ["f" b " " 1]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use dynamic refinements in Red to solve that simply:

```
f: func [x /a][either a [x + 2] [x + 1]]

>> f/:a 1
== 3
>> a: false
== false
>> f/:a 1
== 2
```

You can also use new `apply` for that:

```
>> apply :f [1 /a (2 < 3)]
== 3
>> apply :f [1 /a (find "hi" "o")]
== 2
```

Notice that the value following the refinement is converted to a `logic!` value in order to determine if the refinement is passed or not to the function call.

See the related [blog entry](https://www.red-lang.org/2023/06/dynamic-refinements-and-function.html) for more info.